# why there is no any concept of near, far & huge pointer in 32 bit compiler?

Tags: c, x86

Why there is no concept of near,far & huge pointer in a 32 bit compiler? As far as I understand, programs created on 16 bit 8086 architecture complier can have 1 mb size in which the data segment, graphics segments etc are there. To access all those segment and to maintain pointer increment concept we need these various pointers, but why in 32 bit its not necessary?

Comment: Do you want to tag this with `x86` or are you interested in any CPU type?

Comment: You would need to do serious rewriting to get such a program to work on current machines (assuming it doesn't do intimately machine-dependent stuff like frobbing graphics directly, or calling into BIOS "for performance", in which case it'll be almost hopeless). What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8):

32-bit compilers can address the entire address space made available to the program (or to the  OS) with a single, 32-bit pointer.  There is no need for basing because the pointer is large enough to address any byte in the available address space.

One could theoretically conceive of a 32-bit OS that addresses > 4GB of memory (and therefore would need a segment system common with 16-bit OS's), but the practicality is that 64-bit systems became available before the need for that complexity arose.

Comment: Your second paragraph is pretty much [wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address_extension). Even with PAE, individual processes will typically still only be able to address 2^32 bytes, but the OS itself can and does address more.

Comment: +1 Such `theoretical` OS/architectures exist.  I am quite sure IBM makes a Power/PowerPC (possibly AIX) box like this.  The key is 32-bit virtual and greater than 32bit physical. `PAE` is Intel only.

Comment: @Eric
will you plz give me any link where i can read all these stuff

Comment: @ashrafiiqbal `developer.intel.com`, look for `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual`, get all of it in one document, `Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 3A and 3B`.

Comment: @BillPringlemeir: Interesting.  I was not aware of that.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: One *could create an architecture* that uses segment registers plus a 32-bit offset to address > 4GB of memory just as 16-bit systems use a segment register and a 16-bit offset to address > 64K.  I did not claim that a *real* architecture does that, though Bill says there may be at least one.  With PAE conceptually an application could address just as much memory as the OS, if the OS were designed to permit it.  Still, one process can only address at most 4GB (under 32 bit Windows 2GB) at once with a 32 bit offset.

Answer (score 2):

> why there is no concept of near,far & huge pointer in 32 bit compiler?

It depends on the platform and the compiler. Open Watcom C/C++ supports near, far and huge pointers in 16-bit code and near and far pointers in 32-bit code.

> As i know programs created on 16 bit 8086 architecture complier can have 1 mb size in which datasegment graphics segments etc are there. to access all those segment and to maintain pointer increment concept we need these various pointers, but why in 32 bit its not necessary?

Because in most cases near 32-bit pointers are enough to cover the entire address space (all 2<sup>32</sup> bytes = 4 GB of it), which is not the case with near or far 16-bit pointers that as you said yourself can only cover up to 1 MB of memory (strictly speaking, in 16-bit protected mode of 80286+, you can use 16-bit far pointers to address up to at least 16 MB of memory, that's because those pointers are relative to the beginning of segments and segments on 80286+ can start anywhere in the first 16 MB since the segment descriptors in the global descriptor table (`GDT`) or the local descriptor table (`LDT`) reserve 24 bits for the start address of a segment (2<sup>24</sup> bytes = 16 MB)).